# Cannot hide Spinners ina ScrollView

Tags: android, widget, android-spinner, android-appcompat, android-scrollview

Spinners do not get hidden after they pass the bounds of the scroll view for some reason. I know the problem is with the appcompat spinner because I tried other widgets (such as rey5137's spinner) and they work perfectly fine with the scroll view.

Here is the code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.spinners.MainActivity">

    <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:text="YOU SHALL NOT PASS !!!"/>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingEnd="5dp"
                    android:text="NormalSpinner:"/>
                <Spinner
                    android:layout_width="200dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingEnd="5dp"
                    android:text="ReySpinner:"/>

                <com.rey.material.widget.Spinner
                    android:layout_width="200dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    app:spn_dividerColor="@color/colorAccent"
                    style="@style/Material.Widget.Spinner"
                    app:rd_style="@style/Material.Drawable.Ripple.Wave"
                    />
            </LinearLayout>

            <!-- spamming the same spinner layout above -->
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingEnd="5dp"
                    android:text="NormalSpinner:"/>
                <Spinner
                    android:layout_width="200dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp" />

            </LinearLayout><LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingEnd="5dp"
                android:text="NormalSpinner:"/>
            <Spinner
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp" />

        </LinearLayout><LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingEnd="5dp"
                android:text="NormalSpinner:"/>
            <Spinner
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp" />

        </LinearLayout><LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingEnd="5dp"
                android:text="NormalSpinner:"/>
            <Spinner
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp" />

        </LinearLayout><LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingEnd="5dp"
                android:text="NormalSpinner:"/>
            <Spinner
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp" />

        </LinearLayout><LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingEnd="5dp"
                android:text="NormalSpinner:"/>
            <Spinner
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp" />

        </LinearLayout><LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingEnd="5dp"
                android:text="NormalSpinner:"/>
            <Spinner
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp" />

        </LinearLayout><LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingEnd="5dp"
                android:text="NormalSpinner:"/>
            <Spinner
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp" />

        </LinearLayout><LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingEnd="5dp"
                android:text="NormalSpinner:"/>
            <Spinner
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp" />

        </LinearLayout><LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingEnd="5dp"
                android:text="NormalSpinner:"/>
            <Spinner
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp" />

        </LinearLayout><LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingEnd="5dp"
                android:text="NormalSpinner:"/>
            <Spinner
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp" />

        </LinearLayout><LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingEnd="5dp"
                android:text="NormalSpinner:"/>
            <Spinner
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp" />

        </LinearLayout><LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingEnd="5dp"
                android:text="NormalSpinner:"/>
            <Spinner
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp" />

        </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is pic of what is going on:
[The issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ITys8.png)

Answer (score 0):

Appears to be (as of March 2017) a platform defect (see https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=199453). You'll probably have to use one of the other spinner solutions until a bug fix is released.